# Cannot activate conda activate llmops-course for for Git hubs IDE for LLMS

Tags: conda

I have confirmed and followed all steps laid out in
https://github.com/AI-Maker-Space/Interactive-Dev-Environment-for-LLM-Development/tree/main

When I get to activate conda environment using the command in wsl '''conda activate llmops-course"''' I get:

EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment: llmops-course
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.

When using the command ''' conda info --envs''' I get :

The following is returned
conda environments:
base                  *  /home/crigano/anaconda3

What am I doing wrong please and thanks!

Comment: I am trying to get this running to start a high school course in AI and appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Are you sure you have ran the command `conda create --name llmops-course python=3.11 pip` after installing anaconda?

Comment: No, I didn't ! Thanks so much. Getting back after a three year layoff ... If I am using Juniper notebook does it make a difference?

Comment: Not your fault. I blame it on the tutorial. This command is not mentioned anywhere below "Let's get started", but only under "Tools we'll be using->conda" as an example command

Comment: I havn't looked at the tutorial in more detail, but the approach I would take is a) create an environment with python and all the packages I want b) install the ipykernel in this env c) open jupyter notebook and select the kernel from the newly created env. This let's you install specific packages into the env without messing up your base.

Comment: Thanks very much! I found alot of "depricated" messaging methds in openAI in the tutorial as well! Waiding through :-)